# localparam of struct type - using default values - still requires initializer?

Tags: system-verilog

Should a `localparam` of a `struct` type still require an initializer if it has default initial values?

Eg

```
typedef struct {
 int a = 1;
} my_struct;

localparam my_struct m;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemVerilog syntax/semantics requires a declaration assignment for any `localparam` declaration, or a `parameter` declaration outside the module header (i.e. inside the module body).

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates a syntax error on 3 major Verilog simulators.  From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.20.1 *Parameter declaration syntax*:

> It shall be legal to omit the constant_param_expression from a
> param_assignment or the data_type from a type_assignment **only within
> a parameter_port_list**.